# While trying to find a element on a webpage using Selenium 4 i get this error

Tags: python, windows, selenium-chromedriver

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/sony-playstation-5-console/6426149.p?skuId=6426149")
# driver.get("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/macbook-pro-14-laptop-apple-m1-pro-chip-16gb-memory-512gb-ssd-latest-model-space-gray/6450853.p?skuId=6450853")
driver.maximize_window()

CountryBtn = driver.find_element("xpath", '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]/img')
CountryBtn.click()
print('Selecting United States...')



driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
driver.set_script_timeout(10)

BuyButton = False

while not BuyButton:

    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        BuyButton = driver.find_element("ID", 'fulfillment-add-to-cart-button-23588856')

        print('Add to cart button is not available yet refreshing')

        time.sleep(1)

        driver.refresh()

    except:

        BuyButton = driver.find_element("ID", 'fulfillment-add-to-cart-button-49190634')

        print('Adding to cart')

        BuyButton.click()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post your _full error log_ so we know what's the error.

Comment: So, what is the error? For what code line?